# how to plot countour curve on top of scatter plot in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, contour

I am using Octave plot() function to plot scatter points on a 2D graph. And then I am using the contour() function to draw a contour on top of the points. But the contour() function is not overlapping on top of the points. What happens is that the scatter plot graph is replaced entirely with the contour, even though I am using the HOLD ON command. 
I have something like this:

```
plot();  %plot the x,y scatter plot
hold on; %hold on to be able to add to the plot
contour(); %Add the contour on top of the scatter plot
```

I wonder if someone can show some sample code they can show to add a contour to an existing plot.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
   x = [-10:0.1:10];
   y = x  .^ 2;
   z = x' * x;
   hold on;
   contour(x,y,z);
   plot(x,y);
```

Will yield this graph (in blue you can see the parabol issued by plot).

[image]